# getting an error when pushing to github using Mac osx?

Tags: git, github, git-push

The steps i took exactly on the terminal

went to the project directory i want to push:

```
>git remote add origin git@github.com:hackrvinchi/jquery.checkbox.git
>git push origin master
```

but i get this error, i don't know why

**ssh: connect to host github port 22: Operation timed out
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly**

Comment: "connect to host github"? Not github.com?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The git URL is wrong. it should be:

git@github.com/hackrvinchi/jquery-checkbox.git

not jquery.checkbox.git

See here: https://github.com/hackrvinchi/jquery-checkbox

EDIT 2: (fixed URL)

So to fix it, do this:

```
git remote rm origin
git remote add origin git@github.com:hackrvinchi/jquery-checkbox.git
```

Then try pushing again

Comment: thanks for your answer, how can i remove the current remote, because it says that i already remote that exists +1 upvote :)

Comment: Updated answer to clarify... see the instructions in grey. FYI you could alternatively edit {repo root}/.git/config which is where the remote definition is stored. Just edit the URL, has the same effect.